# Formatted output to text file

Tags: c#

I would like to know how I can make formatted output to a text file.

For example, if I have the value **5.00** in a variable and I want the text file to be written with 9 digits, i.e. 5.00 is written as **000000500**

Comment: Mask for a text file? You can just replace text from a textfile, you can add a mask to a textbox but a mask to a textfile?

Comment: Don't you want decimal separator `.`?

Comment: What's the underlying problem? Are your input strings like `1.2` and `1.234`, which you want to write as `0...012` and `0...01234`, or are your inputs decimal numbers which you want to write with exactly two decimal places and without a decimal point?

Comment: have a variable that is called total and this variable is the total of the purchases I require the value of these purchases to go to 9 digits, for example if it is 5 euros, to be 000000500

Comment: @PedroAzevedo First, have you tried anything, like eg using a format string? Second, why? Removing the decimal separator just *begs* for some very expensive bugs. Especially if you have to handle currencies without cents at some point. Removing the separator *won't* solve localization problems either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to do this because I'm connecting an API from a cashkeeper, so I need to create an automatic testo file with the value of the total in decimal

Comment: @PedroAzevedo 5.00 to 000000500 is quite confusing. you want to convert 5 to 500 neglecting 0 appended. or you want to convert 5.00 to 000000005

Comment: @BhubanShrestha i need convert like 5 euros to 000000500

Comment: @BhubanShrestha this isn't confusing. Many old systems do require unseparated numbers, assuming the final two digits are decimals

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you know how i can do it?

Comment: Andreas already posted the answer. You can use this format string with any method that accepts a format string, like `FileStream.WriteLine` eg `fs.WriteLine("{0:000000000} {1:yyyyMMdd} {2}",d*100m,date,whatever);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(d * 100).ToString("000000000")
```

with `d = 5.00`

outputs: `000000500`

Comment: You don't need `PadLeft`, just use a custom format string with 9 zeroes `000000000`. This avoids generating a temporary string for each value.

Comment: Of course.. thanks

Comment: @AndreasZita that doesn't output 000000500 instead outputs 000000005. Questions seems invalid as he wants to convert 5 to 500. It might be correct if he wants to multiply input with 100 first and then convert resulting number to 9 digit format.

Comment: The question is not invalid. Converting a number 5 to a string "000000500" is nothing strange at all. And the code I proposed does that just fine.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha huh? The snippet works just fine. Did you *try* it? The question isn't invalid either. Wait until you have to parse or generate files for IATA - EBCDIC. Last character `}`. Or some stock exchange protocols that *don't* have decimals

Comment: I checked here http://rextester.com/live/MEO97955

Comment: @BhubanShrestha checked *what*? That's not the answer's code. Try the answer's code and you'll see that it works just fine

Comment: yeap I didn't noticed that * 100. Sorry